# dynamic year binding with drop down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using MVC3/Razor and want to bind a drop down with current plus 3 previous year Number like,

```
2011
2010
2009
2008
```

How to do this? Please help

Comment: is there any way to put ViewData to persist selecetd year. on first load it should show current year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the below to view to create the dropdownlist (change Model.Year to correct property on the model)

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Years",new SelectList(ViewBag.Years as System.Collections.IEnumerable,Model.Year))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year)
    </div>
```

Add below to somewhere in your controller or helper class

```
 private void GetYears()
    {
        List<int> Years = new List<int>();
        DateTime startYear = DateTime.Now;
        while (startYear.Year <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(3).Year)
        {
            Years.Add(startYear.Year);
            startYear = startYear.AddYears(1);
        }
        ViewBag.Years = Years;
    }
```

And then add below line to whatever method will be called to return the view (i.e. Index)

GetYears();

Answer (score 2):

Using above solution but with an alternative for GetYears()

```
    private void GetYears()
    {
        ViewBag.Years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 4);
    }
```